# Programmatically run xml using cmd and c#

Tags: c#, xml, iis, cmd

I'm using C# to create an application that will install IIS unattended.
So far I have this :

```
string currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
string backOneDir = Directory.GetParent(currentDir ).ToString(); 
string backTwoDir = Directory.GetParent(backOneDir ).ToString(); 
string cmdCommand = "start /w pkgmgr /n:"+backTwoDir+@"\iis_scripts\unattend.xml";

Process.Start("cmd.exe",cmdCommand);
```

But nothing happens, not even an error.

I test the cmd command and its working, but not from inside my C# code.
My xml file resides within my project folder inside a folder called iis_scripts.

Any suggestion?

Comment: one comment, may be off topic: you should use Path.Combine(backTwoDir, @"\iis_scripts\unattend.xml"); instead of directly concatenate your path.

Comment: I would check whether the process is running also what happens if you only do Process.Start("cmd.exe",cmdCommand) with a blank command?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the command line arguments passed to cmd won't make it execute the command. To make cmd execute a command on startup you need to use the /k switch.

I believe correct command should be

```
string cmdCommand = "/k start /w pkgmgr /n:"+backTwoDir+@"\iis_scripts\unattend.xml";
```